# What's the most idiomatic way to implement "live communication" with a process?

Tags: rust, process, ipc, daemon, channel

I have a program that runs in the background without any intervention.

However, I'd like to provide some control over running instances. Usage might look something like this:

```
$ foo start
# an instance starts running in the background
```

```
$ foo refresh bar,baz
# the running instance does something with bar and baz
```

What's the typical way of implementing something like this? Is there a way to share channels between instances somehow? How do I *locate* the existing instance in the first place?

Comment: This isn't necessarily Rust-specific since you're talking inter-process communication. You can use any of the common IPC mechanisms, such as: UNIX sockets, signals, named pipes, shared memory, TCP/UDP sockets, files, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way for this would be to use a client-server approach.

`foo start` can be starting a server.
To start it in background as a daemon from the macOS shell:

```
pkill foo && nohup foo start > out.log 2>&1 &
```

or simply (in some cases could be enough):

```
foo start &
```

On Linux it could be configured as a systemd service, init script or a cron job.

`foo refresh` can be a client that sends a request to the running daemon instance.

If you only need a one-way communication one typical way to do this is to use HTTP (e.g. using [warp](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp) for the server and [reqwest](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest) for the client). In this case a way to locate the running instance would be to define a constant shared port number, e.g. 12345. Then the server can listen on "localhost:12345", and the client can request "http://localhost:12345/refresh?ids=bar,baz".

If you don't want an overhead of the libraries, and your communication  protocol is as simple as you describe, the simplest way would be to use a shared file. In this case a way to locate the running instance would be to define a constant shared file name, e.g. "/var/run/foo/request.txt". Then the client writes to this file a line "refresh bar,baz", and the server detects the change, reads it and does something (potentially output the response to the same file, or some other shared file).